# Session variable wont keep user logged in

Tags: php, authentication

Im trying to create a login system that creates a session if the user logs in to the member page. Once in the member page they can press logout to end the session otherwise if they dont, whenever they open up the login page they are redirected to the member page with their details displayed as if they have just logged in again.

How can i do this?

So far ive got this to create the session:

```
$result = $conn->query($SQL); 

    if ($result->num_rows>0)
    {
        //user information available in database
        echo "Login successful";
        echo "<br><br> re-directing to members page";
        $_SESSION['userlogin'] = $User_login;
        header ( 'refresh:5; url=member.php?id='.$Username ); //re-directing to member page
    }
```

And ive added the if isset:

```
<?php //Start of the PHP script
session_start();


if(!isset($_SESSION['userlogin']))
{

}
```

Comment: Share value of $User_login?

Comment: Avi_BI have started the session right at the top of the page, both these scripts are from the same page

Comment: C2486 - What do you mean?

Comment: Looks like you are checking 'not isset' rather than isset. Lose the '!' . `if(isset($_SESSION['userlogin']))`

Comment: Avi_B Oh i didnt see that, fixed it now, but previously when the user logged in it displayed a hello to the members page message as well as their name grabbed from the mysql database but now it just redirects them to the members page but doesent display their details.

Comment: i am not sure but i think you should redirect your member page here like this.

           
  if ((isset($_SESSION['userlogin']) != '')) 
                     {
                       header('Location: refresh:5; url=member.php?
                     id='.$Username '");
}
?>

Comment: PHP Geek i copied and pasted that code but it makes the rest of my code go grey